# property is always null even after setting up the property in moq

Tags: c#, properties, moq

i'm mocking this interface and i can't seem to provide a default value for the property

```
var moqObj = new Mock<IObjectTest>();
moqObj.Setup(mo => mo.Pages).Returns(2);

var engineMgr = new EngineMgr(moqObj.Object);
```

the code cannot detect that i've set this property "Pages" into 2. help!

Comment: Your code looks fine to me; you could write a small class implementing `IObjectTest` yourself and see if the `EngineMgr` picks up the property correctly, to verify that the bug is actually in the Mock class.

Comment: i isolated the test, when i Assert moqObj.Object.Pages, it returns the proper value. but when I use it inside the class, it returns 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Pages` is a property you need to use `SetupGet`:

```
moqObj.SetupGet(mo => mo.Pages).Returns(2);
```

Comment: i've tried this as well.. still doesn't work. it's just a simple property. do i need to do something in this property to make it work?

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem! i accidentally re-initiated the class from within. silly me.

Comment: You should put this as a comment on your question rather than add another answer :)